# Distribution of density function $p(x)$ and $-\log p(x)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $x$ is a random variable with a distribution that is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, such that it has a density $p(x)$. $p(x)$ is a function of a random variable, as is $-\log p(x)$. Are there any general results about what the distributions of $p(x)$ and $-\log p(x)$ are without specifying any further details?

Comment: Did you try any examples at all, especially to check the claim at the end?

Comment: consider looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: Im considering $\log p(x)$ not $\log (x)$ and not necessarily normal

Comment: Why did the claim "I think −log p(x) should have an exponential distribution" disappear?

Comment: Because I just tried for a normal with mean 0 variance $\sigma^2$. $-\log p(x)$ turned out to be a gamma(0.5,1) shifted along the x-axis by $0.5\log(2 \pi \sigma^2)$